# Attaching a file in Grails using Mail plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, email

I'm using mail 0.9 and it seems that the attachment feature is still not in? Was this [item](http://n4.nabble.com/Mail-Plugin-attachment-td1363144.html#a1363144) still not included until now?

If that's the case, please tell me how to extend a Grails plugin without hacking the code directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that I missed the **Attachment** section in the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail). What I saw was the **TODO** section (that should be updated btw). Anyway, here's a much clearer example than the one mentioned there.

```
String path = "./web-app/images/grails_logo.jpg"

sendMail {
   multipart true
   to 'alfred@fbmsoftware.com'
   subject "Welcome to Grails!"
   body '''
       Greetings Earthlings!
   '''
   attachBytes path,'image/jpg', new File(path).readBytes()
}
```

With this, you can attach any kind of files as long as you properly specify the content type I guess.

Comment: Correct, with mail 0.9, I've been able to get attachments to work as you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Grails plugin ('grails install-plugin mail') works perfectly well even over TLS - see mac.com sending requirements.

However, for those using Outlook or other corporate email systems, I found a slightly different Grails solution using resources.xml and the Spring JavaMail helper classes:

1) Add the following to myapp/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml  (see below)

2) Define the service in your business service as needed.

3) Add a few imports-   done!
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper

> def mailSender

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

  <!-- Mail service -->
  <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="mail.munger.somecorp.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- more bean definitions go here... -->

</beans>
```

Java code to add attachment :

```
  MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage()
  MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper( message, true )

  for ( String recipients : [ customer1, customer2, customer3, customer4 ].findAll { it != null } )
  {
      helper.addTo( str );
  }
  helper.setFrom( "" )
  helper.setSubject( aSubject )
  helper.setText("...")

  FileSystemResource fileResource =
    new FileSystemResource( new File(tempFile) )
  helper.addAttachment( tempFile.substring(tempFile.lastIndexOf( "/" ) + 1), fileResource, "application/pdf" )
```